# Split Column in R

Tags: r

Having an issue in R and hoping to gain some assistance.  What I have after a scrape is over 1000 rows in one column.  What I need is the data to be staggered across columns and not one column.  For example:

```
col
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
10
```

But what I need is:

```
Col1 Col2 Col3 Col4 Col5
1    2    3    4    5
6    7    8    9    10
```

Any assistance is greatly appreciated.  I tried the separate tutorial but got this error:

```
 df <- data.frame(x = c(NA, "a.b", "a.d", "b.c"))
 df %>% separate(x, c("A", "B"))
```

> Error in separate(., x, c("A", "B")) : could not find function "separate

Comment: What about turning it into a matrix and then converting to dataframe:: `matrix(col, ncol = 5, byrow = T)`

Comment: Why would you use `separate()`?  You're not separating anything.

Comment: To modify @dylanjm 's suggestion, you can try: `as.data.frame(matrix(df$col, ncol = 5, byrow = T))` and manually set the names.

Comment: @NelsonGon, dylanjm was definitely on the right path.  With the added as.data.frame it cleaned up the data as i wanted.  Thanks so much!!!